# Running Chained Celery tasks at specific times

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

How can I use a celery chained task, such that the second task runs at a specific time i.e 10:04 PM task 1 -> task 2 (scheduled for tomorrow at 9am)

Answer (score 2):

> Found a solution in case someone else runs into a similar issue

In order to run a chained task at a specific time yo could use the ETA or the countdown.

e.g  countdown

```
chain(
    task_1.s().set(countdown=10),
    task_2.s().set(countdown=10)
).apply_async()
```

e.g eta

```
from datetime import datetime 

chain(
  task_1.s(),
  task_2.s().set(eta=datetime.today().replace(hour=9, minute=00))
).apply_async()
```